# Images in list in form Django, How?

Tags: django, list, image, forms

Dear masters! Please help me with this question.

models.py

class New_tables(models.Model):

```
TYPEBET_CHOICES = (
    ('1','up'),
    ('0', 'down'),
 
)

type_bet = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPEBET_CHOICES)
```

form.py

```
type_bet = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=New_tables.TYPEBET_CHOICES)
```

how to make sure that when you select from the list, there are not “up” and “down”, but that instead of them a picture is displayed, preloaded in /media/ ?

I didn't find any information on the Internet.